# ffmpeg process how to read from pipe to pipe in c#

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

I need to read audio data from stream 1 to stream 2 passing the data through ffmpeg.
It works great when i input data from file and output to pipe:

```
Process? CreateStream()
{
    return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"sources\ffmpeg",
        Arguments = @"-i input.mp3 -f s16le pipe:1",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    });
}
```

Or when i input data from pipe and output to file:

```
Process? CreateStream()
{
    return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"sources\ffmpeg",
        Arguments = @"-i pipe: -f s16le output.file",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true
    });
}
```

But if i try to do both:

```
Process? CreateStream()
{
    return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"sources\ffmpeg",
        Arguments = @"-i pipe:0 -f s16le pipe:1",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    });
}
```

Runtime will hang in place printing:

> Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'pipe:0':
> Metadata:
> encoder         : google/video-file
> Duration: 00:04:15.38, start: -0.007000, bitrate: N/A
> Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
> Stream mapping:
> Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (opus (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
>
> Output #0, s16le, to 'pipe:1':
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
> Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 pcm_s16le

main function code (it is the same for all examples):

```
async Task Do()
{
    using (var ffmpeg = CreateStream())
    {
        if (ffmpeg == null) return;

        using (var audioStream = GetAudioStream())
        {
            await audioStream.CopyToAsync(ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream);
            ffmpeg.StandardInput.Close();
        }

        //runtime will hang in here

        Console.WriteLine("\n\ndone\n\n"); //this won't be printed

        using (var outputStream = CreatePCMStream())
        {
            try
            {
                await ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
            }
            finally
            {
                await outputStream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the most interesting is if i remove `RedirectStandardOutput = true` string programm will work as expected printing a bunch of raw data to the console.

I'd like to solve this problem without using any intermediate files and so on.

Comment: You need to do the reading and writing from/to ffmpeg concurrently. Right now you attempt to feed all the audio data to ffmpeg before you start reading its ouptut. This leads to the situation that ffmpeg will receive the audio data through its stdin, and starts outputting on its stdout. This goes well until the buffer associated with the redirected output stream gets full. At this point, ffmpeg will block and wait for the output buffer to be emptied. But you are not reading the output stream yet (you are still trying to feed input data), so there is nothing emptying that buffer

Comment: This then leads to your code writing to StandardInput to fill the buffer associated with StandardInput (as ffmpeg is now blocking/waiting and not taking in any further input). So, now audioStream.CopyToAsync will wait for the StandardInput buffer to be emptied. But which doesn't happen because ffmpeg itself is waiting for the StandardOutput buffer to be emptied. Thus, your program can't finish writing audio data, which means it won't ever get to reading ffmpeg's output, which in turn means ffmpeg will be blocked for all eternity. Boom, deadlock...

Comment: To read the data output of ffmpeg while you are still feeding audio data to it, look into utilizing the `Process.OutputDataReceived` event. Alternatively, don't await the writing and reading to/from ffmpeg separately, but start both tasks simultaneously and then use Task.WhenAll to await both running tasks together.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem myself today and struggled to figure out a solution for hours. In the end, I've created a solution that I do not know if it has hidden problems or flaws, but it works for me. Meaning, this isn't an exact answer to your question, but rather a showcase of an example that now works in my similar scenario.

This codes take a `byte[]` array, transcodes it using ffmpeg, and then transmits it to a stream called `sink` in real-time. My specific ffmpeg arguments here convert a raw PCM from mono to surround.

```
private static async Task TransmitAudioData(byte[] audioData, VoiceTransmitSink sink)
{
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg")
    {
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        Arguments = string.Join(" ", [
            "-loglevel panic",

            "-f s16le",
            "-ac 1",
            "-ar 48000",
            "-i pipe:0",

            "-f s16le",
            "-ac 2",
            "-ar 48000",
            "pipe:1"
        ])
    };

    using var process = Process.Start(startInfo)!;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    var stdin = process.StandardInput.BaseStream;
    var stdout = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream;

    process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, args)
        => Debug.WriteLine($"Error while transcoding audio data: {args.Data}");

    try
    {
        var writer = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await stdin.WriteAsync(audioData);
            await stdin.FlushAsync();
            stdin.Close();
        });

        var reader = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            const int chunkSize = 8192;
            var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];

            int l;
            while ((l = await stdout.ReadAsync(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                await sink.WriteAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, l));
            }
        });

        await process.WaitForExitAsync();
        await Task.WhenAll(writer, reader);
    }
    finally
    {
        stdin.Close();
        stdout.Close();
    }
}
```